# No me carga la la imagen al llamarla desde c# xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xaml

Tengo un problema y es que tengo una clase llamada Mascota, esta contienen 3 campos, dos campos string (Nombre y Descripcion) y un campo de tipo image (ImagenMascora).

En el archivo xaml tengo una listview con un origen binding Mascotas

En c# utilicé una lista de tipo Mascotas declarada con el nombre Mascotas y la llené de esta manera

```
    Mascotas.add(new 
    Mascota{
    Nombre= "perro",
    Descripcion = "jdkdkdk",
    ImagenMascota = new 
    Image {Source = "perro"}
   });
```

En xaml en lista mediante un itemtemplate modifique el orden y las posiciones en q iban a salir los datos...

El nombre y descripción cargan pero la imagen no

La imagen ya la añadí a la carpeta drawable en android y al catalogo de archivos (assets) en iOS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu imagen esta agregada en la carpeta de drawable, tu propiedad Imagen cambiala a `string` y pasale el nombre completo de la imagen

```
   Mascotas.add(new 
    Mascota{
    Nombre= "perro",
    Descripcion = "jdkdkdk",
    ImagenMascota = "perro.png"
   });
```

Comment: Me ha servido, muchas gracias amigo!